# help me please output data from value1 to value2

Tags: php

Can any one help me i like to make a search page that will output the all data from value1 to value2. im getting this error Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Search.php form

```
<form action="Search.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="FROM TIME">
<input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="TO TIME">
<input type="submit" value=">>">
</form>
```

Search.php

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("NO connection");
  mysql_select_db("ci")or die("No DATABASE");
  $value1 =$_POST['value1'];
 $value2 =$_POST['value2'];
 $output="";
 if (isset($_POST ['value1'],$_POST['value2'])){
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slogs WHERE TIME BETWEEN
 ".$_POST['value2']." AND ".$_POST['value2']." ");
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($count==0){
   $output='You are not a student';
  } else{
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$TIME.=$row['TIME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$FN.=$row['FN']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$LN.=$row['LN']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$DT.=$row['DT']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


        }
     }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: at a quick glance your select is going between the same two values, is that what you want?

Comment: also, " WHERE TIME BETWEEN ", TIME is a mysql function, so assuming you have a table column of the same name, you need to surround it with backticks.

Comment: Note : Do error handling in your code after running SQL query like `$result ` is empty or not. Then you will come to know where to look for the bug.

Comment: i have a different values. example a user want to get a data from 9:00am to 3:00pm it will output all data from 9:00am(value1) to 3:00pm(value2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding single quotes `'` around the values you query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slogs WHERE TIME BETWEEN '". $value1 ."' AND '". $value2 ."' ");
```

Comment: Thanks its working... i have one question why is it only showing one result? i need to output all the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your search is selecting data between the same two values.
Try this:

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("NO connection");
  mysql_select_db("ci")or die("No DATABASE");
  $value1 =$_POST['value1'];
 $value2 =$_POST['value2'];
 $output="";
 if (isset($value1,$value2)){
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slogs WHERE TIME BETWEEN
 ". $value1 ." AND ". $value2 ." ");
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($count==0){
   $output='You are not a student';
  } else{
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$TIME.=$row['TIME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$FN.=$row['FN']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$LN.=$row['LN']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$DT.=$row['DT']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


        }
     }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: It still giving me a error of  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,